# How to make Select2 work with dependent form in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4.1, select2-rails

I have "select country" and "select city" forms, If "select country" have no value, it shows "Please select country" text, When I selected country it will load "select city" from. It work fine.
However, when I try to use select2 jquery, the select2 work only with "select country" form but it won't apply to "select city" form.

This is my code:
in _form.html.erb

```
   <div class="field">
         <%= f.label :country %><br>
         <%= f.country_select :country, priority: %w{TH SG MY}, prompt: "Please select a country" %>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :city %><br />
        <%= render partial: 'subregion_select', locals: {parent_region: f.object.country} %>
   </div>
```

in _subregion_select.html.erb

```
  <div id="subregion-field">
       <% parent_region ||= params[:parent_region] %>
       <% country = Carmen::Country.coded(parent_region) %>
       <% if country.nil? %>
               <em>Please select a country above</em>
       <% elsif country.subregions? %>
               <%= subregion_select(:address, :city, parent_region) %>
       <% else %>
               <%= text_field(:address, :city) %>
       <% end %>
 </div>
```

in addresses.js.coffee

```
  $ ->
        $("select#address_country, select#address_city").select2
              width: '250px'

        $('select#address_country').change (event) ->
               select_wrapper = $('#subregion-field')

              $('select', select_wrapper).attr('disabled', true)

              country = $(this).val()

              url = "/addresses/subregion_options?parent_region=#{country}"
              select_wrapper.load(url)


        $('select#locals').change (event) ->
        $(@).closest('form').submit()
```

Thank you so much for your answers.